# Deleting a particular object in NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

My Categories Dictionary is like this

```
    "category": {
        "position": 1,
        "updated_at": "2012-11-21T11:02:14+05:30",
        "is_default": false,
        "name": "Ge",
        "folders": [
            {
```

How can i delete a particular Category object alone which has is_default as true?

I tried the following --

```
for(id obj in category )
{
       if([obj isEqualToString:@"is_default"] && [[category objectForKey:@"is_default"] isEqualToNumber:@0])
       {
```

but was unable to find a way to access the key of the particular category and hence delete it.

Comment: How do you want to "delete" this object?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more about what you are up to and what we are looking at. I guess we look at your JSON input? Of what type is `catebory`? And what do you want to delete when `"is_default"` is `false`?

Comment: Unclear question. Is the first chunk ("category") a bit of JSON you are parsing into nested dictionaries? Is Category a class? One of the nested dictionaries?

Comment: "category" is the key.  There can only be one "category" in a dictionary.  See if the "category" object has "is_default" set true, and, if so, delete "category".  There should be no need for enumeration.

Comment: (Hint: Quit trying to simply copy/modify code from elsewhere and actually take the time to understand the data structure you actually have.)

Answer (score 2):

First thing first: ***You can not delete object from Dictionary(or Array Or Set) while Enumerating.***

But it is not impossible.

Try this:

```
NSArray *keys = [category allKeys];

for(NSString *key in keys )
{
       obj = [category objectForKey:key];

       if([key isEqualToString:@"is_default"] && [[category objectForKey:@"is_default"] isEqualToNumber:@0])
       {
          [category removeObjectForKey:key]
       }
}
```

Comment if you face any problem.

Al The Best.

Comment: Probably you mean `if([key isEqualToString:@"is_default"] && [obj isEqualToNumber:@0])` ?

Comment: @Mat Thanks to draw my attention.

Comment: `"is_default"` is a key, not a value.

Comment: @HermannKlecker I m not getting your point. Will you please explain it.

Comment: You have mended your answer while I was reading it and writing my comment.  It is ok now that you fixed it. But now: what do you need `obj` for?

Comment: Also, as i pointed out you can just use `obj` on the rigth condition, since if the left condition return `true` you have the right object on the right, otherwise the right condition is not evaluated.

Comment: You both are right. But condition is not main part of my Answer. Condition can be change for him for for other who is reading answer. And he may need obj in further code or someone else may want to knw. So i demonstrate that how one can Enumerate using keys and get value. and delete object from dictionary on some condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the keys (an object may be stored in the dictionary multiple times, using different keys) that your object is stored at like this:

```
NSArray *keys = [myDictionary allKeysForObject:obj];
```

Now that you have the key(s), it's easy to delete the object:

```
if (keys.count > 0) {
    [myDictionary removeObjectForKey:keys.lastObject];
}
```

Searching through the values of a dictionary is a relatively slow operation, by the way. If you do this very often, a dictionary might not be the best data structure.

Comment: I think you meant `removeObjectForKeys:` and there's no need for declaring key as `id`. `allKeysForObject:` will return a `NSArray`.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella, if he meant that then he would remove all objects for all keys. Meaning he could simply use `removeAllobjects:`. Frankly I don't think that is even close to solving the problem. The remarks about performance, though, are quite right.

Comment: You're right, guys, I don't know what I was thinking when I posted that. It'd never have worked. I made the answer to his main question (how to find the key for a value in a dictionary) a bit more clear. The answer is also more generic now, so hopefully a little more helpful for future readers.